# Problema al capturar errores con try/except

Tags: python

Tengo este problema a la hora de capturar el error:

```
         try:
                ack_event = PlatformEvent(
                notification_event_id=event['detail']['originalEvent']['id'],
                source=event['source'],
                event_type=event['detail']['originalEvent']['detail']['eventType'],
                region=event['region'],
                timestamp=event['time'],
                organization_id=self.get_notification_event_organization_id(event['detail']['originalEvent']),
                success=event['detail']['success'],
                result=event['detail']['result'],
                event_json=event,
            )
            ack_event.save()

            self.logger.info(f"Saved Acknowledgement Event: {event}")
            return self.create_http_response(True, status_code=200)
        except Exception as e:
            msg_event = f"Error saving acknowledgement event: {event}"
            msg_error = f"Error: {e}"
```

el mensaje que capturo en el Exception como "e" si en el evento que recibo hay alguna propiedad mal como por ejemplo "originalEvent" el exception solo me captura el string "originalEvent" sin detalle de cual es el error.
Habria alguna manera de capturar mas detallado el error o que estaria haciendo mal en este bloque ? Gracias

Comment: Si entiendo bien, querés que se muestre el error completo sin que se interrumpa el programa? Incluyendo el numero de linea, dentro de que función ocurrió, etc?

Comment: Exacto!, para poder darle al usuario un mejor entendimiento de que paso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

Cuando conviertes un objeto de error en cadena, estás obteniendo unicamente el mensaje que te muestra (no el traceback ni el tipo de error). Si quieres obtener más detalles, ofresco una solución alternativa:

#### Solución Alternativa

Para obtener toooda la información del error en forma de cadena como si realmente hubiera sucedido, tendremos que usar un par de modulos de la librería estandar (sys y traceback).

**Código de ejemplo**

```
import traceback
import sys

d = {}

try:
    # esto genera un keyerror
    d["a"]
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

**Produce**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File [censurado], line 7, in <module>
    d["a"]
KeyError: 'a'
```

#### Explicación de la solución

Suceden muchos procesos aquí que no creo sea buena idea enfocarme a explicar. Pero digamos que lo que hace es imprimir la excepción manejada actualmente (actual clausula except) y mandarla al archivo sys.stdout (que es donde envía los datos, por ejemplo, print).

#### Referencias

- [sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)
- [traceback.print_exc](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc)